# Javascript function from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have an array of strings which define class names. I would like to instantiate these classes using the string name. I have tried to use window but I haven't been able to do it.

The structure is

```
var objects = ['string1', 'string2'];
```

So the window would look like

```
window [
    objects [
        'string1',
        'string2'    
    ]
]
```

I have tried:

```
new window['objects'][0];
```

But that threw the string is not a func error.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `window` is a reserved word in javascript, why are you using it?

Comment: To gain access to variables in the global scope

Comment: @ryan: `window` is definitely not a reserved word. Seems clear that OP is making reference to the global object,.

Answer (score 2):

`window.objects[0]` is a string.
You want to get the property of `window` named by that string:

```
window[window.objects[0]]
```

Comment: What does that have to do with creating objects by string name?

Comment: he means you can do new window[window.objects[0]]( )

Comment: ...although new window[objects[0]]( ) is shorter and just as good

Comment: hm, i tried window[window.objects[0]] and also window[objects[0]] and they both came back as undefined

Comment: window[window.objects[0]] would return window['string1'] which doesn't exist since it's in the objects array of window

Comment: @CarlMarkham: Then I have no idea what you're trying to do.